# Are mxSignpost events visible in Xcode Organizer?

Tags: ios, xcode, performance, xctest, metrickit

I can wrap some important code (where I want to observe performance change with new App Versions) in

```
let handle = MXMetricManager.makeLogHandle(category: "Custom Category")
mxSignpost(.begin, log: handle, name: "Custom Event Name")
```

and

```
mxSignpost(.end, log: handle, name: "Custom Event Name")
```

And as far as I understand when I use `MXMetricManager.shared.add(someClass)` and in `MXMetricManagerSubscriber` delegate I receive reports every 24 hours, these reports will contain a separate performance sections for the intervals between `mxSignpost(.begin)` and `mxSignpost(.end)`.

**The question:**

Can I see these performance separation in Xcode Organizer for "Custom Event Name" or "Custom Category" from the code above?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Metric organizer doesn't have this feature from the doc:

> MetricKit goes beyond the metrics shown in the Metrics organizer to include average pixel luminance, cellular network conditions, and durations associated with custom OSSignpost events in your app. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metrickit/improving_your_app_s_performance.

The only way to get signpost info it's inspecting `MXMetricPayload`:

```swift
import UIKit
import MetricKit

@UIApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        MXMetricManager.shared.add(self)
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        MXMetricManager.shared.remove(self)
    }
}

extension AppDelegate: MXMetricManagerSubscriber {
    func didReceive(_ payloads: [MXMetricPayload]) {
        for payload in payloads {
            if let signpostMetrics = payload.signpostMetrics {
                for metric in signpostMetrics {
                    print(metric.description)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @iUrii , I'm giving the bounty to you 

Comment: Unfortunately, the `payload.signpostMetrics` array is always empty

Comment: @adnako Did you ever find a solution to the empty signposts issue? I created a question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75684983/metrikkit-signpostmetrics-is-always-empty

Comment: Posted a comment there