# MetrikKit: signpostMetrics is always empty

Tags: ios, swift, analytics, metrickit

I have set up `MetricKit` in my iOS app in order to send performance measurements taken from `os_signpost` to my custom analytics endpoint.
I did the setup like it is described for example here:
https://nshipster.com/metrickit/
or here
https://www.avanderlee.com/swift/metrickit-launch-time/ .

This is the relevant code:

```
import MetricKit

class AppDelegate: UIApplicationDelegate {
 func application(_ application: UIApplication
        , didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: LaunchOptions?) -> Bool {

        MXMetricManager.shared.add(self)
        // ...
    }
}

class Elsewhere {
    func someFunc() {
        // I verified that this is indeed being called

        let log = OSLog(subsystem: OSLog.subsystem, category: "someFunc")
        let signpostID = OSSignpostID(log: log, object: self)
        os_signpost(.begin, log: log, name: "someFunc", signpostID: signpostID)
        // some code
        os_signpost(.end, log: log, name: "someFunc", signpostID: signpostID)
    }
}

extension AppDelegate: MXMetricManagerSubscriber {

    public func didReceive(_ payloads: [MXMetricPayload]) {
        for payload in payloads {
            for metric in payload.signpostMetrics {

                // this never gets called because signpostMetrics is always empty :(
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So my problem is, that `signpostMetrics` is always empty. I would expect it to contain the data that got collected by the os_signpost in my code.

Comment: "did the setup like it is described for example here: https://nshipster.com/metrickit/" Except no your didn't, since neither of those example use `os_signpost`. Basically you've confused two things that happen to have the name "signpost". `os_signpost` is for use with Instruments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [MetricKit methods](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/metrickit/3214364-mxsignpost)

`mxSignpost(.begin, ...)`

`mxSignpost(.end, ...)`